# How can I find the columns returned by a postgresql query without running the query itself?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

Given a messy postgres query (e.g. with lots of subqueries) is there a way to figure out what columns will be returned by the query without running the query itself?

If I understand correctly, Sequel's `Dataset#columns` method ([Documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-columns)) calls the query with a `LIMIT 1` attached.  That's fine for a simple query, but if subqueries are involved it seems that this approach still results in computing those subqueries.

(One approach might be to add a LIMIT 1 to every subquery, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.)

I'm using Postgres 9.2 with [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/).

Thanks!  (I know this question isn't as precisely posed as might be desirable -- please let me know what more information I can provide that might be helpful.)

Comment: could you add the query itself?

Comment: I'm looking for a generic procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with explain and add the option VERBOSE. Have a look here

```
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html
```